# SEM_FAILED on GCC Red Hat 4.8.5-39 - Semaphores

Tags: c, gcc, semaphore, shared-memory

This is simple  shared memory program that I tried writing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define SHM_NAME "/my_shm"
#define SEM_1 "/sem_1"
#define SEM_2 "/sem_2"
#define SEM_3 "/sem_3"
#define BUFFER_SIZE 10

typedef struct {
    int pred[8];
    int succ[8];
} fb_set;

struct sharedMemory{
    int rPos;
    int wPos;
    fb_set storage[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int done;
};

static struct sharedMemory *shared;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int shmfd = shm_open(SHM_NAME, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0600);
    if (shmfd == -1){
       // exit
    }

    if (ftruncate(shmfd, sizeof(struct sharedMemory)) == -1){
        // exit
    }

    shared = mmap(NULL, sizeof(*shared), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shmfd, 0);
    if (shared == MAP_FAILED){
       // close resources
    }

    sem_t *sem_read = sem_open(SEM_1, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0600, 0);
    sem_t *sem_write = sem_open(SEM_2, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0600, BUFFER_SIZE);
    sem_t *sem_mutex = sem_open(SEM_3, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0600, 1);

    if (sem_read == SEM_FAILED){
        // close resources
    }
    if (sem_write == SEM_FAILED){
        // close resources
    }
    if(sem_mutex == SEM_FAILED){
        // close resources
    }
}
```

All semaphores are open correctly and the program compiles with:

> gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0

But when I try it on:

> gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)

I get `SEM_FAILED` on `sem_t *sem_read = sem_open(SEM_1, O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0600, 0);` and `errno` is set to `Permission denied`.

Here is my Makefile:

```
CC = gcc 
DEFS = -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_SVID_SOURCE -D_POSIX_SOURCE=200809L
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -g $(DEFS)
supervisor: supervisor.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ -lrt -pthread
supervisor.o : supervisor.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
clean:
    rm -rf *.o supervisor
```

Can somebody explain me what I did wrong?

Comment: What does `errno` tell you?

Comment: @alk I forgot to put that, but errno is set to `Permission denied`

Comment: "*`Permission denied`*", so well. Isn't this a clear statement to you?

Comment: @alk I mean, I know what that means, but still don't understand why do I get that on one gcc version but not on the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *`errno` is set to `Permission denied`.*

From `shm_open()` [documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shm_open.html):

> [EACCES]
>       The shared memory object exists and the permissions specified by oflag are denied, or the shared memory object does not exist and permission to create the shared memory object is denied, or O_TRUNC is specified and write permission is denied.